# How to get/calculate total memory used by process in .net?

Tags: .net, memory

I want to calculate total memory used by a process in .net. Total memory here includes both pagefile and RAM usage. The closest I have found is VirtualMemorySize64 in Process class but it is always a bit lower than total memory usage as shown by third-party memory diagnostic softwares.

Comment: VirtualMemorySize64 should be the correct property to use and I'm surprised that its smaller than expected.  What other tool(s) / counters are you talking about?

Comment: I use VMMap which always shows total memory greater than what I get from VirtualMemorySize64.

Comment: Interesting - I'm not sure.  My best guess is that VMMap is counting extra "memory" (like "Unusable" memory), but I can't see what.

Comment: Thanks for your guess. I think you're right. I ended up using System.Diagnostics.Process.VirtualMemorySize64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Justin. I ended up using `System.Diagnostics.Process.VirtualMemorySize64`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are purely interested in physical memory, you probably want [WorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx), which gives "the amount of physical memory allocated for the associated process." Understand that this value constantly fluctuates, and the value this call gives you may not be up to date. You may also be interested in [PeakWorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64.aspx), which gives "the maximum amount of physical memory used by the associated process."

In order to calculate the pagefile use [PagedMemorySize64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.pagedmemorysize64.aspx). "The value returned by this property represents the current size of memory in the virtual memory paging file used by the process. The operating system uses the virtual memory paging file in conjunction with physical memory to manage the virtual address space for each process."

Comment: This only includes the physical memory used by the process and does not include the pagefile useage.

Comment: Sorry about, I just edited my answer to include about the page file usage

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "total memory used by my process" is undefined, as there are many different kinds of memory and they mean different things and there are many questions you need to answer to define it exactly. Here are some of them:

1. Do you include code both code and data, or only data?
2. What if this code is currently shared with other processes (for example, a common DLL that is used by both).
3. Do you include only Committed memory, or all the memory that is Allocated?
4. Your process can allocate memory as "shared" but it currently doesn't share it with anybody. So it will not appear in any working set, but it is actually used only by your process.

There is an excellent two-part lecture that can answer your questions. But you need to invest 2 hours of your time to watch it :). [Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405) and [Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406).